# " No module named 'pycurl' " exception when adding apt repo in terminal

Tags: 13.04, add-apt-repository

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 a few hours ago. After installing some softwares, I surprisingly find I just can't add apt repo in terminal any more!

When I excute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox` , the terminal just throws me these debug message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 148, in urlopen
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 129, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 105, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    import pycurl
ImportError: No module named 'pycurl'
```

I find it reported as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1157900), but that bug thread didn't mention any solution.

Can anyone help me? Thanks so much!

---

After `sudo apt-get install python3-pycurl`, when I `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox` again, I got this strange message:

> Cannot access PPA
>   (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~tiheum/+archive/equinox) to get PPA
>   information, please check your internet connection.

But actually my Internet connection is working fine(e.g. I can `sudo apt-get update`). 
What's on earth with my `add-apt-repository`?